# 403 (Forbidden) - Load a image from external url (HTML)

Tags: html, image, http-status-code-403, http-status-codes

I'm trying to loading an image from external URL
like

```
<img class="comp_img" height="400px" src="http://iphoto.ipeen.com.tw/photo/comment/1070532/741292/cgm226a48af3ab7ddd5d0af714f82c6a9ce309.jpg">
```

it shows error 403 (Forbidden) .

I can't access the image server and I don't want to download these images(about 1 million images), 
and I'm sure the others images URL can work, 
only this website's images showing  403 error code.

How can I solve it?

Comment: It gives you a `403 Forbidden` error. What could that possibly mean? (Hint: you aren't allowed to remotely link to their website)

Comment: you should check file permissions for that.